# How to set dependency based on existence of a variable in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I tried setting up dependency using a variable existence but getting syntax error.

```
│ Error: Invalid expression
│ 
│   on prometheus.tf line 231, in resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "prometheus-pvc":
│  231:   depends_on = [local.aws ? kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth : null]
│ 
│ A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and
│ indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template
│ expressions, etc are allowed here.
```

Any suggestion how to implement that?

There may be n number of reasons for having the above conditional dependency. I don't know why it is necessary to answer the question (why) when you can directly answer the question (how).
In my case, the tf file is part of repository where it is shared by both GCP and aws. So, If I add the dependency directly it would fail the GCP.
Please don't take it to do a different direction of asking questions on why again.
And, please don't reply as maintain a separate file.

Comment: Can you edit your question to say more about the underlying problem you are trying to solve? It isn't clear from your question why it would be useful to declare this dependency in a conditional way, rather than just writing `depends_on = [kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth]`

Comment: Added details above, please check

Comment: In your question you have stated "I add the dependency directly it would fail the GCP", but I don't believe that is true. You are taking a combative attitude that makes it difficult to understand your underlying problem in order to help you find a solution that will work for you. If your question is just "how can I declare a dependency conditionally?" and you are not willing to consider any other possibilities then I cannot do any better an answer than "what you want to do is not possible".

Comment: If you would like to continue here (no problem if not), please change your question to be a description of the underlying problem you want to solve, ideally including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what is failing when you declare just `depends_on = [kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth]`, and then I would he happy to help you find a way to solve that underlying problem with Terraform.

Comment: I didn't understand what exact information you are looking for. I explaining clearly that the tf file is shared by two different project files as base kubernetes. And if I keep the aws_auth directly, in aws project it will work and in gcp it will fail. So,trying to make it based on condition.  What else you need @MartinAtkins

Comment: `depends_on = [kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth]` will work as long as there is a `resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth"` block in your module. If your resource block contains something like `count = local.aws ? 1 : 0` then that's already enough to make this work, because Terraform can see that `kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth` refers to a resource with no instances, which is correct. If that isn't working then please share a code example with the unconditional `depends_on` along with which error message you see when you try that.